# How do I delete multiple rows from a table that has 2 composite key with multiple values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table that contains a list o telephones from organizations. This table has 2 columns a foreign key to the table Organizations (ID) and telephone.

**Telephones**

```
ID  Telephone   
1   1234
1   3456
1   9999
3   9999
```

I want to delete the fist and second rows, for doing this I have the ID value 1 and a table containing the numbers to delete ( 1234, 3456) called `@TempTels`

I thought of this but it didn't work :

```
Delete From TelephonesOrg 
where ID = ID AND Telephone = (Select Telephone from @TempTels)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that sub-select returns more than one value, you need to use `IN` - not an `=` equals sign:

```
Delete From TelephonesOrg 
where ID = 1 
  AND Telephone IN (Select Telephone from @TempTels)
```

Comment: Just tried it, worked flawlessly. thanks!. May I ask you how the IN statement works?

Comment: @DanteSnow: the `IN` operator checks to see if the value on the left (`Telephone`) is in the result set on the right (your sub-select). And if so - it's a match, and the row is processed. It works like an equal sign - only against a whole **collection** of values - not just a single value.

Comment: Thanks again, Sounds like a real useful

Comment: @DanteSnow, given your first comment, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  You may find it worthwhile to learn some fundamental skills rather than fumbling about as you try to do things.

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try. I have an sql book but is most centered on tools than SQL language, so it doesnt quiet help most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

@Dante Snow from your code you have 3 rows having id=1..so if you want to delete first 2 row only you have to use like below..

```
Delete From TelephonesOrg 
where ID = 1 AND Telephone in (1234, 3456)
```

Comment: It would work if the values where static but I was writing a Stored Procedure. Thanks for your time.